# C# Bouncycastle Blowfish CTR decryption

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, bouncycastle, blowfish

I'm having a bad time trying to figure out how to use the C# bouncycastle library to decrypt a blowfish CTR ciphered text.I'm not getting how to use it due to the lack of BC documentation about how to use it properly.

I searched extensively without found something similar in stack overflow, If you have some examples about how to use BC to encrypt/decrypt in Blowfish CTR mode cipher using BC C# libraries will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, after a long week I decided to use AES CBC instead Blowfish CTR using Zeroes as padding.

Comment: Zero padding is a weird choice, since it doesn't allow you to reconstruct the original text. And you should consider adding authentication.

Comment: Basically I encrypted a JSON, the receiver JSON parser parses the padded text (like {key:value}0000) without any problem with the leading zeroes, I got other authentication mechanisms as well.